# HTTP POST request in Android causing server to crash

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get this to work. I'm using OkHTTP to make a POST request to my server. However, every method I've tried of making a successful POST request with parameters, causes the server to go down, giving me a response of '503 service unavailable'. I use exterior clients to test the server, like the Advanced Rest Client extension, and it works perfectly fine.

The URL for the API is in the format of "https://mystuff-herokuapp.com/postuser" and my body parameters are "user_id", "userName", "email". I've tried adding headers to the request, changing from FormBodyEncoding() to MultiPartBuilder(), etc etc.

**onCreate**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    //set toolbar as the acting action bar
    Toolbar actionToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(actionToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String photoUrl = intent.getStringExtra("photo");
    String userTwitterID = intent.getStringExtra("userID");
    String userName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String userEmail = intent.getStringExtra("email");

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jObject.put("user_id", userTwitterID);
        jObject.put("userName", userName);
        jObject.put("userEmail", userEmail);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    new UserApiProcess().execute(jObject);
}
```

**Async Task**

```
private class UserApiProcess extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... strings) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                .addFormDataPart("user_id", "800")
                .addFormDataPart("userName", "Nick")
                .addFormDataPart("email", "something@something.com")
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://mystuff.herokuapp.com/postuser")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if(!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Successful Response from Advanced Rest Client**
[image]

**My Server Error through Android**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should work.

```
private class UserApiProcess extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... strings) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodinBuilder()
            .add("user_id", "800")
            .add("userName", "Nick")
            .add("email", "something@something.com")
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://mystuff.herokuapp.com/postuser")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
    Response response = null;
    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if(!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        System.out.println(response.body().string());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: That worked! I tried this before but I think the server may have been down when I tried so I figured it was on my end. Thanks!